# Set text on TextView on button click from another class on android

Tags: java, android

​Hi everyone,

If anyone can explain me why the following code not working would be great!
So, I want to set text on a TextView on button click by calling a method from another class. All this just try to keep methods belong together in same java file for example all methods regarding animations in Animations.java. But I cannot figuring out how to do it and always got NullPointerException​ fault.

Here is the **main class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



public SeconClass secondClass = new SeconClass();
TextView myview;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myview =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    myview.setText("First class");


   final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            secondClass.ChangeText();

        }
    });
}

 }
```

and the **second one**

```
public class SeconClass extends AppCompatActivity {

 TextView myview;

public void ChangeText(){

    myview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    myview.setText("From second Class");
}

}
```

Comment: `SeconClass` is an `Activity` which is special case of class(and you not provide any `onCreate` methods at all, also there is no contentView for that Activity).   You have to switch to that Activity etc., you can't use that as a normal class as you do.Also I don't understand your purpose.

Comment: Its not like java. At first understand the Android Concept then try coding in Android. For reference you can refer http://developer.android.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be possible, you have to pass the value you want to set in text view using intent. You have to use intent and pass the value from one activity and get that value in another activity and than set the value to text view.

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, your activity name where you want  to send the value);
intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent1.putExtra("otp", verificationCode);
context.startActivity(intent1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `TextView` as parameter for the second `class`

```
public class SeconClass extends AppCompatActivity {
     public void ChangeText(TextView myview){
        myview.setText("From second Class");
     }
}
```

Now when button clicked:

```
secondClass.ChangeText(myview );
```